# Google Sheets I want to calculate Today Stock price / 2 days ago but only for market days

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate closing price of stock for today (which should be trading day not weekend) / 2 days ago which also should be trading day

```
=index(sort(GOOGLEFINANCE(B7, "close",today()-2,3),1,0),2,2)
```

I tried this but not working

Comment: Are you sure you want to calculate this? This formula (what you described, not what you entered into the spreadsheet) will only work on 3 days per week: Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. On all other days, either "today" is not a trading day or "2 days ago" is not a trading day. The day you wrote your question is a Sunday, so no trading day - even if the formula is correct (didn't check it), it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate the close price for a stock using GoogleFinance where the effective date is `TODAY()`. But, if "today" occurs on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday), then you want the close price for the previous Friday.

Try this formula for the data value:

`=if(weekday(today())=1,today()-2,if(weekday(today())=7,today()-1,today()))`

---

The formula uses `WEEKDAY()`

- `weekday(today())=1` = "SUNDAY"

  - the reference date is `today()-2`
- `weekday(today())=7` = "SATUDAY"

  - the reference date is `today()-1`
- if the date is neither a Sunday or Saturday, then the reference date = `today()`